# Pass Data From First ajax to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

Right off the bat I want to apologize that I am not posting code with this. I'm in a car working on a project and I have no internet. I am on the awesome stack exchange app.

Anyway, I am currently working with two separate API calls that I know work separately, but I need to use data from the first call to pass to the second one in order to use the second one dynamically. The reason being, the first AJAX request is a call to Google's geocoding API to get the latitude and longitude of an address. The second requires latitude and longitude as URL parameters.

I looked into using jQuery $.when and .then, but I can't figure out how to pass the data from one AJAX request to the other. I have also tried to build to separate functions and use one inside of the other.

I guess my question is would this be the most efficient way to do this? If it is how do I pass the data.

Side note, responses in jQuery are good for now. I am eventually going to convert this all to Node, but I just want to get the method down first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i got you correct, u can call the second ajax request in the success callback of the first one like below example

```
$.get('ur resource URL',function(data){
    $.get('new resource URL',{param1: data.param1, param2: data.prama2}, function(data2){
       console.log(data2);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was going to try this but i didn't know if it was best practices. I wanna make sure i use the correct method

Comment: Although it will work, this is not following best practices. It will make your code harder to maintain. It's worth having a read of http://callbackhell.com/.

Comment: in my opinion, for you case as you know it is just 2 nested requests it is not bad practice, i see no need for a sophisticated solution for a trivial case

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using `$.post()`:

```
$.post("url_with_address", function(data){

    // process geocode API response

    $.post("url_with_lat_long", function(response){
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I didn't know if running another call inside of the success message was best practices

Comment: That's not a success message. it's the success `callback` from `$.post()`. it returns the data from the request. you can process the data returned from the 1st and add it to the url for the 2nd request.

Comment: Right right. I knew what you saying. I just used the wrong term. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tried and tested async utility library such as [async](https://github.com/caolan/async). This will future proof your code, as it will work in the browser as well as in Node.

In specify, take a look at the [waterfall](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall) method which allows you to chain together a number of async calls, this will help you manage the code if you need to add more dependent async calls in the future.

The structure of the waterfall function is as follows.

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback){
      $.post('http://google.com/api/...', data, callback);
    },
    function(results, callback){
      $.post('http://google.com/api/...', results, callback);
    }
  ], function (err, result) {
    // all done
});
```

If you want to use jQuery, then the `$.when` utility won't be that helpful, as it only resolves when every promise has resolved and you want to intercept the data before then.

The simplest way, of course, is to make the second AJAX request within the callback for the first one. However, that is a surefire way to get you on the path to callback hell.

Comment: Callback hell! Haha! For sure! Thanks for suggesting this library. I will look into it. I thought about callback hell and i was wondering if there was a better way.